# python plot how to adjust a lengthy legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

My existing plot has more than 30 legend-labels. I want to show all of them by adjusting the legend. 
My existing plot is : 
[image]

I am trying to achieve something like below: 
[image]

My existing code:

```
plt.legend(rsh_df.columns[0::2].values.tolist(),bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left', borderaxespad=0.)
```

Any idea about how to achieve it?

Comment: Tried the `ncol` argument?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes! I got it by setting `ncol=2`. Thanks a ton. Simple solution.